# Calculate the total derivative without using partial derivatives

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Calculate directly the total derivative (without using partial derivatives) of the function $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2−10x_2$.$$$$
I have tried to show it using the following formula: $f(x+y)=f(x)+dfx(y)+r(y)$, where $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ r(y)}{||y||}=0.$ So we have $f(x+y)=(x_1+y_1)^2-10(x_2+y_2)=x_1^2+2x_1y_1+y_1^2-10x_2-10y_2=f(x_1,x_2)+2x_1y_1+f(y_1,y_2)$. Now considering the formula above; 2x1y1 is the total derivative, but when I check the total derivative using the partial derivatives I get an additional "-10" as a result, but I don't know how to show it without partial derivatives. Can somebody help me solve it step by step, please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471167/calculate-total-derivative-directly/4471188#4471188

Comment: I don't understand the answers, that's why I wanted a step by step explanation.

Comment: Notice that $x_1\,y_1 \leq |x_1|^2+|y_1|^2$ is a second order term, it does not appear in the derivative.